# Autocomplete google maps searching with directions , issue I need its solution necessary?

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript, ionic3

In my attempts to implement autocomplete map included from google maps I have written this code :

```
import { Component , ViewChild , ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions ,Geoposition ,PositionError } from '@ionic-native/geolocation'; 


declare var google ;
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html',
})
export class TestPage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement : ElementRef;
  map: any;

  @ViewChild('origion-input') originInputElement: ElementRef;
  originPlaceId: any;

  @ViewChild('destination-input') destinationInputElement: ElementRef;
  destinationPlaceId: any;

  @ViewChild('mode-selector') modeElement: ElementRef;
  travelMode: any;

  directionsService : any ;
  directionsDisplay : any ;

  lat : any
  lng : any 
  Auto : any

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private geolocation: Geolocation) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestPage');
  }

  ngOnInit(){

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);
    let mapOption = {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 13
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement , mapOption);

// here the error in next line => 
   this.Auto = new google.maps.AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(this.map);

  }
   AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
    this.map = map;
    this.originPlaceId = null;
    this.destinationPlaceId = null;
    this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
    let originInput = this.originInputElement ;
    let destinationInput = this.destinationInputElement ;
    let modeSelector = this.modeElement ;
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    let originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
    let destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});

    this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
    this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
    this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
  }

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  //AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.
  setupClickListener(id, mode) {
    let radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    let me = this;
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      me.travelMode = mode;
      me.route();
    });
  }

  //AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.
  setupPlaceChangedListener(autocomplete, mode) {
    let me = this;
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.place_id) {
        window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
        return;
      }
      if (mode === 'ORIG') {
        me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
      } else {
        me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
      }
      me.route();
    });

  }

  //AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.
  route() {
    if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
      return;
    }
    let me = this;

    this.directionsService.route({
      origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
      destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
      travelMode: this.travelMode
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

  }
```

but it give me an error about this line

```
this.Auto = new google.maps.AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(this.map);
```

and the error it gives to me is that :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: google.maps.AutocompleteDirectionsHandler is not a constructor
TypeError: google.maps.AutocompleteDirectionsHandler is not a constructor
    at TestPage.webpackJsonp.460.TestPage.ngOnInit (test.ts:51)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12095)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13598)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TestPage_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14740)
    at TestPage.webpackJsonp.460.TestPage.ngOnInit (test.ts:51)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12095)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13598)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TestPage_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14740)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at Tab.NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:223)
    at Tab.NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:216)
    at nav-controller-base.js:263
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4629)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
```

and if I delete the line which cause the error then the code will not give an error but also will not run properly 
when I delete the error line then the result it is the map doesn't appear in the view

the html code is :

```
<ion-content padding>
    <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter an origin location">

<input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a destination location">

<div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
  <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
  <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
  <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
</div>

<div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

What I should do to solve that issue ?

Comment: Looking at your code it looks like `AutocompleteDirectionsHandler()` is just a method of `TestPage` class. I would say you should use something like `this.AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(this.map);` in your code.

Comment: but there is no error red line but it didn't view properly , and I try your suggestion but it give me an error line under word "this" :/

Comment: please any help :/ I need it very necessary